# How to add a question mark after date when the date is uncertain in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, date, authoryear

First a MWS and its output are as follows.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{somebook1769,
  location = {Place},
  author  = {Name, Given},
  title   = {Some title of this publication},
  date    = {1769?},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
some quote from \cite[1348--1368]{somebook1769}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see,  I add a question mark after the date but it isn't printed. Then how to add a question mark after date when the date is uncertain in biblatex?

Comment: Use double question mark, it should work.

Comment: @Houcine Unfortunately not.

Comment: Sorry but I forgot to mention the package : `\usepackage[dateuncertain=true]{biblatex}`

Comment: Please don't edit the question to move the goalpost after you have already gotten good and helpful answers for the previous state of the question. The edit has essentially invalidated the two answers. Instead ask a new question: That way the old question and its answers can remain and help future visitors.

Comment: @moewe I open a new question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/673948/140814).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add  `dateuncertain=true` in biblatex.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,dateuncertain=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{somebook1769,
    location = {Place},
    author  = {Name, Given},
    title   = {Some title of this publication},
    date    = {1769?},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
  some quote from \cite[1348--1368]{somebook1769}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Here is my LinkedIn : https://www.linkedin.com/in/el-houcine-brahim-457b8511b/

Answer (score 1):

Normally it is preferred to use `date` instead of `year` in biblatex, but maybe you can get away with it in this case:

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{somebook1769,
  location = {Place},
  author  = {Name, Given},
  title   = {Some title of this publication},
  year    = {1769?},
  sortyear= {1769}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
some quote from \cite[1348--1368]{somebook1769}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]