# How to add parenthesis around the question mark after the date which is uncertain in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, date

First a MWS and its output are as follows.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,dateuncertain=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{somebook1769,
  location = {Place},
  author  = {Name, Given},
  title   = {Some title of this publication},
  date    = {1769?},
}
@book{somebook1889,
    location = {Paris},
    author  = {Name, Given},
    title   = {Some title of this publication},
    date    = {1889},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
some quote from \cite[1348--1368]{somebook1769} and \cite{somebook1889}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see I add a question mark after the date which is uncertain. **Then how to add parenthesis around the question mark?** For example, change 1769? for 1769(?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro that controls the uncertainty marker is called `\bibdateuncertain`. Its default definition is a question mark, but you can easily add parentheses as follows

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,dateuncertain=true]{biblatex}

\renewrobustcmd*{\bibdateuncertain}{\mkbibparens{?}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{somebook1769,
  location = {Place},
  author   = {Name, Given},
  title    = {Some title of this publication},
  date     = {1769?},
}
@book{somebook1889,
  location = {Paris},
  author  = {Name, Given},
  title   = {Some title of this publication},
  date    = {1889},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
some quote from \cite[1348--1368]{somebook1769} and \cite{somebook1889}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: some quote from Name 1769(?), pp. 1348–1368 and Name 1889 Name, Given (1769[?]).]

Comment: I posted an answer as well, but deleted it. My solution was to use  `\renewcommand*{\dateuncertainprint}{(?)}`, but that resulted in putting a `(?)` after the year in every citation. *BTW* you don't need to load the package `filecontents` anymore to use `\begin{filecontents*} .. \end{filecontents*}`. In fact that package has become obsolete.

Comment: @alchemist Indeed `\dateuncertainprint` is a macro that is used by almost all date printing macros. Its usual definition with `dateuncertain=true` (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/81a5e01777e0b3a79a4d12a3b790f233a9922c3d/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty#L15669) is `\ifdateuncertain{\bibdateuncertain}{}`. So the macro needs to check if the date is uncertain and prints `\bibdateuncertain` only in that case.